# SignalR - OnDisconnectedAsync not called when client disconnects abruptly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I have a SignalR hub with an override for OnDisconnectedAsync. I have found that gracefully closing the connection on the client side - like calling `close()` - will trigger OnDisconnectedAsync. However, the disconnect doesn't seem to trigger when disconnecting "disgracefully".

For example; When I open the client in a tab, click onto a couple of other open tabs, then close the client tab while having another tab in focus. This does not trigger a disconnect.

This also seems to happen when disconnecting from my work's network through a VPN connection. Basically, any condition that falls outwith the normal conditions for a disconnect. It's like the server still thinks the connection is open.

I have tried to reduce the KeepAliveInterval and ClientTimeoutInterval to see if I was just being impatient, but after waiting 5 minutes after disconnecting, I'm convinced it's not firing properly.

Am I doing something wrong in my hub?

```
services.AddSignalR(opts => {
    opts.MaximumParallelInvocationsPerClient = 10;
    opts.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    opts.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
});
```

```
public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
{
    if (exception != null)
    {
        Log.Error(exception.Message);
    }

     Log.Information("${Context.UserIdentifier} Disconnected");

     ...bunch of additional logic

     await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
}
```

Comment: Is the server under a debugger? The disconnect timeout isn't triggered in that case.

Comment: no this is in a hosted environment